# Is there a way to prevent Lords from escaping?

Tags: mount-and-blade, mount-and-blade-warband

I have a quest to capture a Lord from a certain faction, but they keep escaping after I have taken down their armies. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Or at least increase the chance that I will be able to capture them?

Comment: Does your question apply to Warband or the original Mount&Blade?

Comment: Warband, but put both in case there is no difference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may only take prisoner people you have knocked unconcious. You must first take down the Lord, then take down their armies. However, if you take a Lord prisoner he may escape after some time traveling.

Escaping: For every 72 hours the Lord is in your party he has a 50% chance of escaping. If you have a jail in your town, you can put him in their and he only has a 10% chance of escaping

Source:
http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Prisoners

Comment: If they escape after a while, that's ok. I'm mostly annoyed with the initial catching, hehe. Do you have any advice on how to do this? Should I use my own dude to try to hunt down the lord and make sure he's on the ground? Should I order my whole army to use blunt weapons? Think I read somewhere that this maximizes the amount of potential prisoners or something...

Comment: Telling your army to use blunt weapons will make them knock all opponents out instead of killing them, meaning that they all will become prisoners but it also means your army will be _a lot_ weaker since many units - especially archers - don't have blunt weapons and will start fighting with bare hands. However, Lords can't be killed and will be knocked out by any weapon, so using blunt weapons shouldn't be neccessary. I don't know how capturing them is influenced though, for me it appears there is a random chance of them escaping after battle even when knocked out.

Comment: Yeah. I was probably just unlucky then. Had like seven lords get away right after each other :p

Comment: As @dbemerlin said, Lord's cannot be killed (like you!) Therefore, "killing" them in any way will do. Using blunt weapons is good for capturing prisoners, as "normal" units will not be killed.

Answer (score 0):

More prisoner management you have, better are chances to capture a lord.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you whittle down the enemy army first, then knock out the Lord, his chances of escaping are much lower. I guess because he has no men to "drag him away from the fighting" like your men do for you when you fall in combat.